# InputStream misses byte while reading in a loop

Tags: java, serial-port

I'm trying to write a java program to read from a COM port. There are 266 bytes to read, and since the 266 bytes are not generated all together, which means that the input stream can be empty at sometime, I used a while loop to read all 266 bytes. The problem is that **SOMETIMES** one byte may be missed *(only one byte)*, according to my checking the received bytes one by one. Here are the codes:

```
While(numOfBytes < 266) {
    if(!(inputStream.available() > 0)) continue;
    inputStream.read(buffer);
    data[numOfBytes] = buffer[0];
    numOfBytes++;
}
```

Comment: If your input stream is doing a blocking read you should not have to worry about this. Just issue blocking read calls until you have read 266 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You give input stream an array to store data in (is.read(buffer)), but regardless of how much it reads, storing only 1 byte, and incrementing number of bytes by 1.

Try instead something like:

```
    While(numOfBytes < 266) {
        if(!(inputStream.available() > 0)) continue;
        int b = inputStream.read();

        if(b >= 0){
            data[numOfBytes] = (byte) b ;
            numOfBytes++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your codes, but I get what you mean. I'll try it later. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

normally I would do it like this

```
 byte[] in = new byte[4196];
 int bytesRead = 0;
 while ((bytesRead = is.read(in)) != -1) {
     // add to a StringBuffer maybe
 }
```